# Node js serve file body from server and download in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, express

I have a file repository and when i call it from the browser it automatically downloads the file and this is fine. 
But i want to do this request on my server, and then serve the file result to the browser. Here is the example of the get request from my server.

```
downloadFile(req , res , next) {
    let options = {
         url: 'url to my file repo',
    };

    request(options, function (err, resp, body) {
       if (err) {
           res.status(500).send("");
           return
       }

       for (const header in resp.headers) {
           if (resp.headers.hasOwnProperty(header)) {
               res.setHeader(header, resp.headers[header]);
           }
       }
       resp.pipe(res);
    })
}
```

The request is working fine, and when i access my server from the browser it starts downloading the file. Everything seems to work fine except one thing, the file can't be opened. **This file format can't be opened**, says me the image player (if the file is image for example).
Where is the problem, Is it the way i serve the file from the server?
Thank you in advance. I lost a lot of time and can't find the solution.

Comment: try not setting `res` headers.

Comment: @MukeshSharma i tryed a lot of variants with headers, but noone helps.

Answer (score 0):

Because what you probably want to send is the body of the request (e.g. the data of your image).
So instead of resp.pipe(res):

```
res.send(body)
```

Use the developer mode of your browser to check the network messages passing between the server and your browser.

Comment: The same with this response. It downloads the file, the file size is also correct but you cant open it.